# How to detect duplicate request in method post with same time

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I using spring boot and create api with method look like below:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/products/")
@Api(value = "ProductControllerApi",produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class ProductController {
  @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<ProductDto> createProduct(@RequestBody Product product) {
        URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path("/{id}").buildAndExpand(product.getId()).toUri();
        return ResponseEntity.created(location).body(productService.createProduct(product));
    }
}
```

But when user using device call my method(**/api/products/**) with same time, it duplicate create with same data. Example: When use create user look like
{
   "name": "Samsung"
   "cost": "26$"
}

it create two record in database with same data. How to detect duplicate data from different source(example : user using two mobile and call same time with same method and create same data). How to avoid it and if it call same time with same data it only insert one record to database

Answer (score 4):

This isn't a problem for Spring Boot but rather for your persistence layer. The best practice is for your DB tables to modeled in such a way that two identical requests would create exactly the same primary key. Then your application code would deal with any exception from the DB layer at transaction commit time.

Comment: Thanks you but how to i do that. Because my primary key using uuid create it. When it create it create random uuid. I can't handle it.

Comment: @Squall1 You can probably create a candidate key of timestamp+username.

Comment: @Hackinet It mean i must add one column in database with  timestamp + username ? Right

Comment: Yes, create a column/attribute and use it to store concatenate timestamp and username. @Squall1

Comment: @Squall1 if you can't use the PKey then you can create what are called UNIQUE CONSTRAINTS on any arbitrary set of columns.